# Proof by contradiction in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

So we are given the following to prove, **only by proof by contradiction**

$\forall x(Q(x)\to P(y)) \vDash \forall xQ(x)\to P(y)$

Now the first thing that comes to mind in predicate logic when i am on a dead end is to perform **Tarski's theorem** about truth and see what types of structures ,the given types are true. But when it comes to analyzing the first part: $\forall x(Q(x)\to P(y))$ i am not very sure if i can say which structures(we want to find structures as sets, for example:for every x that makes Q true, there is a y that makes P truth etc) Anyway i need help finding the types for structures these types need to be true so after that i can move forward and start the proof by contradiction.Thanks

Comment: In the proof by contradiction, you have to assume a "generic" *structure* where both the premise and $∀xQ(x)$ are true, and suppose that $P(y)$ is *false*.

Comment: so you are saying i dont have to actually find the types of structures, i just have to assume general structures and advance to the atopic?

Comment: well even if i  do this,i dont really know how to start a proof by contradiction in this one. Help me please

Comment: The opposite of $\forall xQ(x)\to P(y)$ is $- P(y)$ and $\forall xQ(x)$  which would mean there exists an x where Q(x) and not P(x), so there exists an x such that it isn't true Q(x) -> P(x) so it's not the case that $\forall x(Q(x) \implies P(x))$.  I think.

Comment: @GrahamKemp : but $∀x(Q(x)→P(y)) \vdash Q(x)→P(y)$ is a correct application of $\forall$-elim, and $∀xQ(x) \vdash Q(x)$ also is. Thus, by $\to$-elim, we get $P(y)$ and finally, by $\to$-intro, we have $∀xQ(x)→P(y)$. In conclusion : $∀x(Q(x)→P(y)) \vdash ∀xQ(x)→P(y)$ and the result must follow from *soundness*. I'm not able to manufacture a "semantic" counter-example ...

Comment: @fleablood - "$\lnot P(y)$ and $∀xQ(x)$ which would mean there exists an $x$ where $Q(x)$ and not $P(x)$ ... " Why? $x$ and $y$ **can be** different, so is not necessary that "there exists an $x$ such that it isn't true $Q(x) \to P(x)$".

Comment: @GrahamKemp - why not ? You can assume it and finally you can "discharge" it by *Deduction Th* (i.e. $\to$-intro) ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that was a typo.  If I typed P(x) I certainly meant P(y).    In either case it's  the "$\forall x $ applies only to the $Q(x)$ and not the P(x) or P(y) or P(sodall) clause

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Suppose $\forall x(Q(x)\to P(y))$
2. Suppose  $\forall x(Q(x))\land \neg P(y)$

Obtain a contradiction, thus negating (2).

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x(Q(x)\to P(y)) \;\models\; \forall x\,Q(x)\;\to\;P(y)$

To prove by contradiction show that $\neg(\forall x\,Q(x)\to P(y)) \;\models\; \neg\forall x(Q(x)\to P(y))$

$$\begin{array}{l}
\neg(\forall x\,Q(x)\to P(y))
\\
\forall x\,Q(x) \wedge P(y)
\\
\exists x\, Q(x)\wedge P(y)
\\
\exists x\,(Q(x)\wedge P(y))
\\
\exists x\,\neg(Q(x)\to P(y))
\\
\neg \forall x\,(Q(x)\to P(y))
\\
\Box
\end{array}$$

(Skeleton only: Justifications and several steps omitted).